# Difference between using str_detect() and contains()?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, tidyselect

I know it might be a silly question, but I was curious if there was any difference, I like more using str_detect because the syntax makes more sense in my brain.

Comment: *(I'm new here so I don't know if I need to put a code for a question like this?)* Then read about it first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are substantial differences. First, `contains()` is a "[selection helper](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html)" that must be used within a (generally tidyverse) selecting function.

So you cant work with vectors or use `contains()` as a standalone function - ie, you can't do:

```
x <- c("Hello", "and", "welcome (example)") 

tidyselect::contains("Hello", x)
```

Or you get the error:

> Error: ! `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.

Whereas `stringr::str_detect` **can** work with vectors and as a standalone function:

```
stringr::str_detect(x, "Hello")
```

Returns:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Secondly, `stringr::str_detect()` allows for regex, and `tidyselect::contains` only looks for literal strings.

So for example, the below works

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Hello", "and", "welcome (example)"))

df %>% 
  select(contains("1"))

#               col1
# 1             Hello
# 2               and
# 3 welcome (example)
```

But this does not:

```
df %>% select(contains("\\d"))
```

(`\\d` is the R regex for "any digit")

Additionally, as noted by @abagail, `contains` looks at column names, not at the values stored within the columns. For instance, `df %>% filter(contains("1"))` worked above to return the column `col1` (since there was a "1" in the column name). But trying to `filter` on the values that contain a certain pattern does not work:

```
df %>% 
  filter(contains("Hello"))
```

Returns the same error:

> Caused by error:
> ! `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.

But you can filter on the values in the columns using `stringr::str_detect()`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_detect(col1, "Hello"))

#    col1
# 1 Hello
```

Lastly, if you are looking for similar functions outside of `stringr`, since `tidyselect::matches()` will accept regex, @GregorThomas aptly points out in the comments,

> "`tidyselect::matches` is a much closer analog to `str_detect()` --though still as a selection helper is is only for use within a selecting function."

`str_detect` is also equivalent to base R's `grepl`, though the orientation of the pattern and string are reversed (ie, `str_detect(string, pattern)` is equivalent to `grepl(pattern, string)`

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `tidyselect::matches` is a much closer analog to `str_detect()`--though still as a selection helper is is only for use within a selecting function.

Comment: Not explicitly stated here (but implied in the selection helper) is that `contains` only looks at the names of variables, not their values. And fwiw to give an example, my most frequent use of `contains` is `mutate(across(contains("date"), ymd))`

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, `contains()` can only be used in a select statement. `str_detect()` can be used in any kind of statement, see @jpsmith's answer.

Furthermore, as mentioned in the documentation of `tidyselect::contains()`:

> [...]`contains()`: Contains a literal string.

> [...] `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, and `contains()` **do not use regular expressions**. [...]

> [...] For `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, and `contains()` **this is an exact match**.

Whereas, in the documentation of `stringr::str_detect` :

> pattern : Pattern to look for. **The default interpretation is a regular expression**.